# I can only update my Vagrantfile when I run `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up`

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

**EDIT:** I'm now able to get into the website, but every time I `halt` and then re-run `vagrant up` I keep getting the same

```
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
```

message. It works perfectly fine if I run `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` from scratch, but obviously this is not ideal. Any ideas?

---

As the title says, I can't get to the actual webpage of http://localhost:8080. It should be noted that I ran terminal commands to install apache2 in the beginning of the entire process.

I can ssh into virtualbox just fine, but when I `curl -v` the URL it comes back with a `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`.

I think it has something to do with the fact that when I run `vagrant reload` or `vagrant reload --provision` it times out and can't connect, even though VirtualBox signals that it is, indeed, running.

I've tried `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`; still can't get into the webpage.

I've tried interacting with the GUI to edit the `ifdown eth0` etc; still can't get into the webpage.

This is my first time playing around with Vagrant and VirtualBox and I'd really appreciate some assistance!

My Vagrantfile is really simple:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
end
```

If anyone can help I'd be so so so appreciative :)